# Gradle fault only inside Android Studio and works great outside

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build, android-gradle-plugin, android-resources

Im working on a project with Gradle 2.14.1 and Android Studio 2.1.3

when I try to build & run the application from the IDE (Android Studio 2.1.3), the output APK results in immidiate crush with the following log:

```
08-16 15:49:47.368 1222-1222/my.package.name D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x0058
08-16 15:49:47.372 1222-1222/my.package.name E/LoginActivity: ******** starting onCreate *******
08-16 15:49:47.372 1222-1222/my.package.name W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f02004e (t=1 e=78) in package 0 (error -75)
08-16 15:49:47.372 1222-1222/my.package.name D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-16 15:49:47.372 1222-1222/my.package.name W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6159908)
08-16 15:49:47.416 1222-1222/my.package.name E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.package.name/com.ngsoft.dynamic_surveys.activities.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
          Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
             at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
             at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
             at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
             at com.ngsoft.dynamic_surveys.activities.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:74)
             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
          Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
             at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660) 
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685) 
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466) 
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
             at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270) 
             at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881) 
             at com.ngsoft.dynamic_surveys.activities.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:74) 
             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 
             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
          Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f02004e a=-1 r=0x7f02004e}
             at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1927)
             at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
             at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3330)
             at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:431)
             at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:176)
             at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:172)
             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 
             at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660) 
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685) 
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466) 
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
             at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270) 
             at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881) 
             at com.ngsoft.dynamic_surveys.activities.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:74) 
             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 
             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 


         [ 08-16 15:49:47.428   428:  443 D/         ]
         HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7f388f8, tid 443
```

It's easy to see that it a drawable issue by the line:

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f02004e a=-1 r=0x7f02004e}
```

so far so good (or bad...) but what got me amazed is that when I use the same Gradle 2.14.1 with this project from command line `gradle build` it produces APK that works.

at the first build from command line gradle brings some dependencies:

```
> gradle build
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.3/gradle-2.1.3.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/2.1.3/gradle-core-2.1.3.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/builder/2.1.3/builder-2.1.3.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint/25.1.3/lint-25.1.3.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/transform-api/2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api/transform-api-2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-api/2.1.3/gradle-api-2.1.3.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/compilerCommon/2.1.3/compilerCommon-2.1.3.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.0.3/asm-5.0.3.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-parent/5.0.3/asm-parent-5.0.3.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/ow2/1.3/ow2-1.3.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/5.0.3/asm-commons-5.0.3.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/proguard/proguard-gradle/5.2.1/proguard-gradle-5.2.1.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/proguard/proguard-parent/5.2.1/proguard-parent-5.2.1.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.core/0.7.6.201602180812/org.jacoco.core-0.7.6.201602180812.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.build/0.7.6.201602180812/org.jacoco.build-0.7.6.201602180812.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/antlr/antlr/3.5.2/antlr-3.5.2.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.5.2/antlr-master-3.5.2.pom
```

but I think that Android studio does this too.

**My Problem:**

How can it be that the same build script produce good APK outside of IDE and bad APK inside?
what am I doing wrong in the IDE?
how it can be solved?

Comment: close Android Studio, got to your project's directory, unhide! hidden files, then remove `.gradle`(hidden normally), `build`,`app/build` folders. after that, run Android Studio - the folders would be recreated

Comment: That's not working, Android studio still compiles bad APK and Gradle from command line compiles it good